# How can I use the subprocess library to call other python files with command-line arguments in a top-level python file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So essentially I have 15 or so scripts that can connect to various networking devices using an SSH library. I want to create one top-level python file that can run other python scripts so the user can decide which scripts they want to run. I have been advised to use the subprocess library and this seems to make the most sense for what I want to do. It is important to note that my python scripts contain command-line argparse arguments for it to run, for example:

```
 python reboot_server.py -deviceIP 172.1.1.1 -deviceUsername admin -devicePassword myPassword
```

So far I have created a top-level python file that is set up to call two python scripts to start with that the user can enter. However, when I run the program and select one of the options I get a "SyntaxError:invalid syntax" Traceback. This happens right when I enter my first argument, which is the device IP address

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys

def runMain():

    scriptName = os.path.basename(__file__)

    print("The name of this script: " + scriptName + "\n")

    while True:
        optionPrinter()

        user_input = input("Please select an option for which your heart desires...\n")

        switch_result = mySwitch(user_input)

        if switch_result == "our_Switch":
            deviceIP = str(input("Enter the IP address for the device"))
            deviceUsername = str(input("Enter the username for the device"))
            devicePassword = str(input("Enter the password for the device"))

            subprocess.call(['python', 'our_Switch.py', deviceIP, deviceUsername, devicePassword])

        elif switch_result == "San_test":
            deviceIP = str(input("Enter the IP address for the device"))
            deviceUsername = str(input("Enter the username for the device"))
            devicePassword = str(input("Enter the password for the device"))

            subprocess.call(['python', 'San_test.py', deviceIP, deviceUsername, devicePassword])

        else:
            print("Exiting the program now, have a great day !\n")
            sys.exit(-1)
```

Here is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/myFolder/src/top_level.py", line 57, in <module>
    runMain()
  File "C:/myFolder/src/top_level.py", line 39, in runMain
    deviceIP = str(input("Enter the IP address for the device"))
  File "<string>", line 1
    172.28.6.21
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Keep in mind that all the scripts that I'm trying to call is in the same source file. Also it is important to note that I have tested each script I have written and they are all fully working. Am I using subprocess.call() right ? How can I fix this issue ? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Must you use Python 2? Can't you switch to Python 3? At this point it's a bad idea to develop new code in Python 2 unless you absolutely must. It's also a less reusable resource in 2019 to have new Q&A in Python 2 than 3.

Comment: @smci It is this weird thing in my company . The products we release still use python 2.7 for some reason and I mentioned that 2.7 will be unsupported soon. I can't argue with my manager, lol.

Comment: Ah. In principle you could do 2-to-3 migration, but management see no reason to, that's why the language is becoming fragmented (like Android phone versions). There are lots of talks, tools, best-practices, tutorials out there - see PyCon, PyVideo, YouTube etc. Test coverage, performance, library compatibility are all factors. The main thing is articulating the "benefits package" to management (e.g. a mix of improved performance, and new 3.6/7 features), figuring out a timeline and milestones, getting them to commit resource. If they still won't do it then move to a different company, or sigh.

Comment: At least for now, suggest you personally write 3.x code in parallel with your 2.x work, or at least figure out how to write 'universal' 2/3-compatible code that can be machine-translated from 2-to-3 with minimal breakage. Look at 'six' package, etc. A lot of packages are written to partition and minimize the 2/3-version-specific bits, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You are using python2. In python2, `input` not only takes input, it evaluates it as python code. Obviously an IP address is not valid python code. Hence the syntax error.

For python2 you should be using `raw_input` - and you can drop the `str`.

```
deviceIP = raw_input("Enter the IP address for the device")
```

Or you can switch to python3